# When I send a HTTP DELETE request to JSON-Server objects are being deleted that should not be

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-delete, json-server

I am trying to delete an object in my *JSON* file by sending the ID of that object via a `HTTP DELETE` request in my Angular app.

Here is my Typescript:

```
cancelOffer(offerId: number) {
  console.log('OFFER ID: ' + offerId);
  this.offerService.deleteOffer(offerId).subscribe(
    () => {
      console.log('Offer Deleted Successfully');
      this.getAllOffers();
    },
    (err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.errorMessage = <any>err;
    });
}
```

- If I pass the ID of 1, all 3 records are deleted.
- If I pass the ID of 3, records 2 & 3 above are deleted.

And here is my `Offer Service` code:

```
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/offers';

deleteOffer(id: number): Observable<void> {
    console.log('Delete Offer Called');
    return this.httpClient.delete<void>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/offers`, this is displayed:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "managerId": 1,
    "jobId": 2,
    "employeeId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "managerId": 4,
    "jobId": 1,
    "employeeId": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "managerId": 8,
    "jobId": 91,
    "employeeId": 1
  }
]
```

Can someone please tell me why my code is behaving this way, & what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: We can't tell without debugging, but what I see you didn't unsubscribe from your service, so I guess it's still side effect of not-subscribed observable or either could be your backend. If you add console log to your service, and your subscription, how many times they are called?

Comment: @RezaRahmati Hi, can you tell me where to put the console.log's?

Comment: before `this.getAllOffers();` and in deleteOffer in your service, also add a `tap` in your service inside pipe and do console log there as well

Comment: @user9847788 The ts code looks okay so it looks like your issue will be in your web api. What is happening on the api running at localhost:3000? If you can, test the api without using angular to help identify where the issue exists.

Comment: @RezaRahmati So I have added the console.log's to the code & added them above also. When I run the code, these are printed out only once.

Comment: Hi @PlantPorridge I am using the following command to run a fake REST API server: `json-server --port 3000 --watch db.json`

Comment: @PlantPorridge Posted some more info relating to my api

Comment: When I delete Offer 3, this is printed out: `DELETE /offers/3 200 6.207 ms - 2
GET /offers 200 2.392 ms - 80`

Comment: Hi @PlantPorridge can you give me some tips/suggestions as to what I should be looking for with the API? I'd be very grateful

Comment: Hi @user9847788 I'd recommend trying to test your api separatley from the angular app to identify the problem area. Use a tool like Postman to try sending the same Delete requests you mentioned above to your api. If the result is the same as when using the Angular app then you know the problem is with the API.